# The C# String.Format() Format Controls

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, string-formatting

```
dgProducts.Columns["Unit Price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

When I execute this code it's displaying the money with $ sign (example: for 432 it is showing as $432.00). But I want "LKR" instead of '$' sign. Is it possible to do that? please help me!

Comment: You are getting $ as the regional settings on the machine are not set to sri lanka, if the regional settings were set to sri lanka then you would get LKR.  Your code is correct. If you want to ignore the regional settings of the client the answer below is what you want

Comment: cheap hack: string.Format("{0:C}", yourDouble).Replace("$", "LKR");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To override the regional settings on the client set the FormatProvider.

```
dgProducts.Columns["Unit Price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
dgProducts.Columns["Unit Price"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider =  new CultureInfo("si-LK");
```

But a better idea would be not to do this and simply ensure that the regional settings on the client are correct

Comment: +1. Note that you'll get .Net currency name (and "LKR" is not the name) - `Console.WriteLine(1.0.ToString("C3", new CultureInfo("si-LK")));` results in `රු. 1.000`, not "LKR 1.0" which will require custom culture to achieve.

Comment: You could get a list of the cultures using 
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);  perhaps there is an english variant for sri-lanka